# How put margin between diffrent div on a container?

Tags: html, css

I have different lines each one contains logo and some text.I want to put each logo in a different line and put a margin-top of 20px between them.

index.html:

```
<container class="list_project">
      <div class="project">
          <img class ="first_logo" src="./logos/logo.png" value="" />
          <img class ="project_logo" src="./logos/logo.png" value="" />
      </div>
    </container>
```

style.css:

```
  .first_logo 
  {
   position: absolute;
   top: 150px;
   width: 85px;
   height: 45px;
  }
  .project_logo
  {
    position: absolute;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 85px;
    height: 45px;

   }
```

But I find that the position of the image is relative to main page not to the container. How can I fix that and I make the position of each image relative to the container?

[Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTRXb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both of them are fixed size, this does the work.

HTML:

```
<container class="list_project">
  <div class="project">
    <img class ="first_logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTRXb.png" value="" />
    <img class ="project_logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTRXb.png" value="" />
  </div>
</container>
```

CSS:

```
.first-logo, 
.project-logo {
  display: block;
  width: 85px;
  height: 45px
}

.first-logo {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make the project `div` as relative.

```
.project{
  position:relative;
}
```

Absolutely positioned div's look for the first relative parent and if none defined, become relative to the body.

Sample Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/dabros/vo1npqdx/